# How to upload the images to s3 bucket using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, multer, multer-s3

I am new to aws. I want upload an image from node js using multer to s3 bucket.

I have followed the tutorial on youtube but am getting stuck with this error.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ASuU4km3VHE&t=1047s

TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined" error.(POSTMAN)

Please help me figure out the problem.Thank you for help

file_upload.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const upload = require("./file_upload");

const singleUpload = upload.single("image");

app.post("/image-upload", function(req, res) {
  singleUpload(req, res, function(err, some) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(422).send({
        errors: [{ title: "Image Upload Error", detail: err.message }]
      });
    }
    return res.json({ imageUrl: req.file.location });
  });
});


app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Listening on Port 3000");
});
```

file_upload_router.js

```
const multer = require("multer");
const multerS3 = require("multer-s3");
const aws = require("aws-sdk");

aws.config.update({
  secretAccessKey: "Your_ACCESS_KEY",
  accessKeyId: "YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID",
  region: "" // region of your bucket
});

const s3 = new aws.S3();

const upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: "upload-image-node-test",
    acl: "public-read",
    metadata: function(req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, { fieldName: "TESTING_META_DATA!" });
    },
    key: function(req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, Date.now().toString());
    }
  })
});

module.exports = upload;
```

I have also made the below changes:-

Block new public ACLs and uploading public objects (Recommended)" to False.

"Remove public access granted through public ACLs (Recommended)" to False too.﻿

I need to get a JSON response with the imageUrl as key and timestamp as filename but i am getting the below error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined"

Comment: Make sure you don’t miss the attr `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the HTML form which sends `/image-upload` request or the header `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` if this is an ajax (if you use Postman)

Comment: Can you please give some more info on how you are making API request from potman.

Comment: Small correction. Use body type `form-data` if you use Postman

Comment: @MaxMartynov I am using postman  and selecting form type with file type to upload the image but still i am getting the above error

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing `location` property of `file` which doesn't exist on request object. Node/Express doesn't handle this automatically.

If you want to have access to `file` on `req` object (without writing your custom handler), then you need to install `body-parser` module and use it as a middleware

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

This assumes that your web form includes field with a name `file`.

Comment: I tried your solution but did not solve my issue. i get the same error

Comment: @Srikanth86in Are you sure that you are sending the data as `urlencoded` and not `application/json` then? If so, you need to use `app.use(bodyParser.json())`

Comment: I am using Postman and  I am using the form-data as i told earlier

Comment: There is no option for me to upload to a file when I select x-www-form-urlencoded . Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @Srikanth86in You are not, my bad. Try removing all headers that you are sending with the request.

Comment: @Srikanth86in Then maybe there is some issue with S3 accessibility. Try to change  public access settings of your S3 bucket where you are uploading the file - uncheck everything (allow everything)

Comment: I did that  as i told you earlier ..i have put everything to false

Answer (score 0):

Can you have resolved but I will one more solution to anyone find it.

Lets you set Block public access (bucket settings) is Off for all.

Click link and then choose "your store" and click "Permission" choose "Block public access"
Link bucket: https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/?region=us-east-1

[image]